# Command Injection in Windows ShellExecuteA()?

Tags: windows, c, winapi

Imagine that we have the following pseudo-code in a Windows application:

```
ShellExecuteA(0, "open", &File, &Parameters, &Directory, 1);
```

And, imagine that you can gain control over the `Parameters` argument. Does that mean it is exploitable ?

I know that `ShellExecute()` is vulnerable to command injection. But, in this case, is it also vulnerable in the same manner ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the `lpFile` argument. If `lpFile` is a command-line interpreter (such as `cmd.exe` or `powershell.exe`) or a program that can accept code as a command line argument (such as `perl.exe` or `ruby.exe`), then yes, you could supply arbitrary commands for a command injection attack.

However, if the `lpFile` program doesn't execute command line arguments (for example, `notepad.exe`, `pbrush.exe`, etc.), then there is no command injection vulnerability. Note that even in these cases though, if the `lpFile` program tries to open the file path supplied in the command line, this could still be seen as a security issue.

Comment: There is obviously a potential issue regarding the length of the parameter field, but even data files can be vectors for exploitation - malformed graphics, too long configuration strings, ...

Comment: Right, assuming this is a server application, even if you can't upload a malformed data file to a predictable file path, you may be able to feed the application a URI or a UNC path to a malformed data file.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason already mentioned, everything depends on file. But I want to say something more.

You said:

> And, imagine that you can gain control over the Parameters argument.
>   Does that mean it is exploitable ?

In the same manner control of other `ShellExecute` parameters *might* be gain... You probably understand why I said *might*, not *can*.

You didn't included info in question, but I think you meant that control of `parameters` is gained editing executable. If so there is such thing.

Imagine file is `cmd.exe` and you can control parameters, but in app parameter is `C:\file.txt` it has 11 characters, so you could change it into some other up-to 11 characters parameter (if it is smaller then 11, you need to add `NULL`s).

However in real situations `ShellExecute` parameters are partially hard-coded and are build dynamically during program flow. So answering to your question, `ShellExecute` is vulnerable to command injection, however, not every app that uses `ShellExecute` could be taken as a target and actual injecting could be not so easy task.